# How long to join a new node to a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I have one Cassandra 1.0.9 server that is set up to be the seed for a cluster. It has ~34gb of data on it. I am trying to join a second Cassandra 1.0.9 to the ring and have the first set up as the seed.

In /var/lib/cassandra/log/cassandra.log I am seeing:

```
INFO 20:06:52,809 JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO 20:07:22,815 JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO 20:07:52,817 JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
.
.
.
INFO 20:10:22,839 JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO 20:10:52,841 JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO 20:11:22,847 JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
```

In /var/log/cassandra/system log I am seeing:

```
INFO [main] 2012-09-11 20:19:52,913 StorageService.java (line 668) JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO [main] 2012-09-11 20:20:22,919 StorageService.java (line 668) JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO [main] 2012-09-11 20:20:52,921 StorageService.java (line 668) JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
.
.
.
INFO [main] 2012-09-11 20:23:22,943 StorageService.java (line 668) JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO [main] 2012-09-11 20:23:52,945 StorageService.java (line 668) JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
INFO [main] 2012-09-11 20:24:22,951 StorageService.java (line 668) JOINING: waiting for schema information to complete
```

Running a netstats gives me:

```
Mode: JOINING
Not sending any streams.
Not receiving any streams.
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed
Commands                        n/a         0              5
Responses                       n/a         0          51966
```

Any idea on how long this should take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that I have resolved this with the following steps:

1. Delete /var/lib/cassandra/data directory (and sub directories) on new server
2. Delete /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/Schema* files on seed server
3. Delete /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/Migration* files on seed server
4. Recreate schema on seed server in cassandra-cli
5. Start up Cassandra on new server

Now I see the new server in the ring even though it is still joining ( it didn't show up in ring on previous join attempts).  Both the seed and new server are on the same Schema, as noted by running "describe cluster;" in cassandra-cli.

I hope this helps someone else out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving ring information should take only a few seconds.

The best way to identify the problem is to turn on debug logging in log4j-server.properties on both hosts.

My guess is that one of hosts can't connect to the other one on storage port (7000 or 7001). There might be different reasons for that: hostname misconfiguration, firewalls, ssl misconfiguration, etc. Try to execute

```
nodetool -h <hostname> ring
```

command, and then try

```
telnet <hostname> 7000
```

from each of hosts to the other one. Make sure that you're using hostnames from nodetool's output.

If both connections work fine, try turning on debug logging.

Comment: Note that `nc` is generally a tool that's easier to use to test a connection than `telnet`. Especially, you can do Ctrl-C to stop it quickly. (`nc -v <hostname> 7000`). It also supports proxies and UDP!